# powershell Win-GetEvent -MaxEvents

Tags: powershell, get-winevent

Trying to assemble PS query into EventLog, and playing with MaxEvents limit. It print zero lines if "MaxEvents" is 1, and it print header line and one event when MaxEvents is 2. Is this correct behaviour, or am I miss something?

```
powershell.exe Get-WinEvent -FilterHashTable "@{ LogName = 'Microsoft-Windows-UniversalTelemetryClient/Operational'; Id = 55} -MaxEvents 2 | where {$_.Message -match 'false'} | ft -HideTableHeader"

ProviderName: Microsoft-Windows-UniversalTelemetryClient

02/02/2020 14:25:04             55 Information      Is the Internet ava...
```

Comment: it looks like your filter AFTER the G-WE call is removing the items that do NOT match `false`. have you looked at the results of the G-WE call itself ... without the filter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See below the result of:

```
Get-WinEvent -FilterHashTable @{ LogName = 'Microsoft-Windows-UniversalTelemetryClient/Operational'; Id = 55}
```

for my PC is:

TimeCreated                     Id LevelDisplayName Message
-----------                     -- ---------------- -------
                                                                                                                                                                                                                           21/01/2020 06:29:23             55 Information      Is the Internet available: true
21/01/2020 05:32:29             55 Information      Is the Internet available: true
20/01/2020 17:23:22             55 Information      Is the Internet available: true
19/01/2020 07:12:06             55 Information      Is the Internet available: true
19/01/2020 07:07:22             55 Information      Is the Internet available: false

If I add -MaxEvents for any value up to 4 then no result

If I add -MaxEvents 5:

ProviderName: Microsoft-Windows-UniversalTelemetryClient

19/01/2020 07:07:22             55 Information      Is the Internet available: false

The -MaxEvents is therefore processed on the result of -FilterHashTable, not on the results from the log.

Comment: Prepend `-MaxEvents` before hashtable section does help me. Working version here: `powershell.exe Get-WinEvent -MaxEvents 2 -FilterHashTable "@{ LogName = 'Microsoft-Windows-UniversalTelemetryClient/Operational'; Id = 55} | where {$_.Message -match 'false'} | ft -HideTableHeader"`

Comment: Wondering why your output is not truncated and my one is? I got only part of string `Is the Internet ava...` but there is a full string in your output `Is the Internet available: true`. I am unable to parse output for words 'true' or 'false'

Comment: Possibly because of the way you're running it, it's returning a string not an object - why are you using 'powershell.exe'?. Try inserting Select TimeCreated,Message into your command before output.

Comment: This command is a part of batch script, because eventlog 'Microsoft-Windows-UniversalTelemetryClient' is not accessible via WMI (utilizing getwmiproperty.exe tool in my case), thus I have to read it by PS and parse output in FOR loop. As I know nothing about PS, just blindly trying assembling suitable command :-/ I do not know how do I incorporate 'Select TimeCreated,Message' into my command. Just tried few variants, but have no luck...

Comment: Got it, thanks a lot! `powershell.exe "Get-WinEvent -MaxEvents 1 -FilterHashTable @{ LogName = 'Microsoft-Windows-UniversalTelemetryClient/Operational'; ID = 55} | Select-Object -Property TimeCreated,Message"` But anyway, is there any option to disable string truncate in PS output?